# Entity Framework Many-to-Many Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm moving across to Entity Framework as part of an ASP.Net MVC application I'm developing. Using code-first, I'm trying to get a simple many-to-many mapping working for a user role listing.

I have the following classes (and related database tables)

```
public class User 
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    // etc...

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserRoles
{
    public int UserRoleID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
}
```

and an `OnModelCreating` override which maps the many-to-many relationships...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany<Role>(u => u.Roles)
        .WithMany(r => r.Users)
        .Map(ur => {
            ur.MapLeftKey("UserID");
            ur.MapRightKey("RoleID");
            ur.ToTable("UserRoles");
        });
}

public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

When a user is authenticated, I make the currently authenticated `User` object available as part of a custom `IPrincipal` implementation.

```
public class MyPrincipal : IPrincipal
{ 
    // User attached to this custom IPrincipal
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

And the authentication request stage which makes the `User` available in `Global.asax`

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the FormsAuthentication cookie
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        // If the cookie exists
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            // Get the authentication ticket
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            var identity = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name, "Forms");
            var principal = new WebStoresPrincipal(identity);

            // Get the userdata from the ticket
            string userData = ((FormsIdentity)(Context.User.Identity)).Ticket.UserData;

            // Deserialize the JSON data
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            principal.User = (User)serializer.Deserialize(userData, typeof(User));

            // Set the context user
            Context.User = principal;
        }

}
```

However - maybe this is where I'm not understanding correctly or missing the point altogether - when I try to access the `Roles` to which the `User` is assigned, it is an empty collection whereas I had expected the Entity Framework to have populated the `Roles` collection.

So, given I have the following data:

`Roles`
RoleID, Name
1, Administrator
2, Contributor
3, Proof Reader

`Users`
UserID, Name, etc
1, Bob Smith
2, Joe Bloggs

`UserRoles`
UserRoleID, UserID, RoleID
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 3

I would have *expected* that if I view the data returned for `User` 1, I would see the `Roles` collection contain a single entry for `Administrator` role.

Clearly, I missing something fundamental here but having trawled through tens of websites, nothing beyond setting up the many-to-many is explained.

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you are getting the User. Probably you're missing an **Include** in the query

Comment: additionally `UserRoles` model is redundant in this scenario

Comment: @AdilMammadov Please explain why UserRoles is redundant?

Comment: @weblar83, in many to many relationships, table which is in-between is redundant. It is necessary when you use it like, `public class User { public virtual ICollection<UserRoles> UserRoles { get;  set; }  }` and `public class UserRoles
{
 public int UserRoleID { get; set; }
 public int UserID { get; set; }
 public int RoleID { get; set; } 
 public virtual User User { get; set; }
 public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the `User` object you are deserializing from the ticket is not attached to the database. Then EF will not load the Roles from the Roles table into this object.

Try loading the User from the DbContext instead.

```
// after "Deserialize the JSON data"
var loadedUser = dbContext.Users.Find(principal.User.UserId);
```

This object should have a populated Roles collection.

Comment: perfect! That works a treat, thank you! I didn't really want the database queried each time the AuthenticateRequest was called but given that its an intranet application, I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Maybe you can get away with loading the Roles only in the LogOn action (and then storing them in the ticket). This would entail that Users have to log in again after their Roles have been changed.

Comment: I had considered this just, however I like the idea of roles being reflected "on the fly" rather than the user having to log out and log in again.

Comment: One thing that now occurs when I try to access the `Roles` property at a later stage is that I get an ObjectDisposedException. As the DbContext is wrapped in a `using` block, as soon as Dispose is called then the Roles collection is disposed

Comment: Try to copy them into the principal `principal.User.Roles = loadedUser.Roles.ToArray();`

Comment: I altered the User loading function as follows: 
    `principal.User = db.Users.First(u => u.UserID == storedUser.UserID);` which now persists the data following the Dispose. I guess its something to do with "lazy loading"...

Comment: Or that the EF query has not been executed before the context has been disposed. Queries can be materialized by calling `.ToArray()` or similar.

Comment: Is there a better way to guarantee that execution has completed or to force eager loading in this scenario rather than lazy loading?

Comment: I think the problem was that the query was not executed, not lazy loading. You can try `db.Users.Include(u => u.Roles).First(/* ... /*);` to force eager loading.